# How to glob file name pattern matching in linux using c++ 98

Tags: c++, linux, glob, c++98, file-globs

Below is the piece of code, where I am trying to find file with matching pattern from directory path provided.

the expectation is to list all the files with pattern matching,
for example under *"/usr/local"* path, the below files are present
**abc.txt axy.txt bcd.txt azz.txt bby.txt**

with pattern matching code, i am expecting the below output

```
       abc.txt
       axy.txt
       azz.txt
```

```
#include <glob.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> glob(const string& pattern) {
    
        // glob struct resides on the stack
        glob_t glob_result;
        memset(&glob_result, 0, sizeof(glob_result));
    
        // do the glob operation
        //int return_value = glob(pattern.c_str(), 0, globerr, &glob_result);
       int return_value = glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_result);
        if(return_value != 0) {
            globfree(&glob_result);
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "glob() failed with return_value " << return_value << endl;
            throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
        }
    
       // collect all the filenames into a std::list<std::string>
        vector<string> filenames;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < glob_result.gl_pathc; ++i) {
            filenames.push_back(string(glob_result.gl_pathv[i]));
        }
    
        // cleanup
        globfree(&glob_result);
    
        // done
        return filenames;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        vector<string> res;
        res= glob("a");
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo i have re-edited question explained what is expected output also i have made changes for header file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo while execution of this code i am getting coredump

Comment: You don't catch the exception you throw, this makes your program abort.

Comment: `glob("a"` only matches a single filename, namely `a`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. so glob("a*" will this work? and how to get rid of core dump i am getting

Comment: Do not throw an exception you are not planning to catch.

Comment: And after you found no matches, you call `globfree`. I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. i am not throwing exception now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo agreed and made my changes to code, now i dont see core dump but the output i get is empty.

Comment: @AMITHKOTIAN Hmm, I ran the program in my answer and got a match on all files having an `a` in the name. What's the result when you run it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i copied your code and tried to compile on c++98 i got compilation issues

Comment: @AMITHKOTIAN My bad, I forgot that it was C++98 - Fixed it now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes working for me now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll only match on a file named exactly `a`, you `globfree` when you shouldn't and thrown an exception that you don't catch.

```
#include <glob.h>

#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string& pattern) {
    glob_t glob_result = {0}; // zero initialize

    // do the glob operation
    int return_value = ::glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_result);

    if(return_value != 0) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));

    // collect all the filenames into a std::vector<std::string>
    // using the vector constructor that takes two iterators
    std::vector<std::string> filenames(
        glob_result.gl_pathv, glob_result.gl_pathv + glob_result.gl_pathc);

    // cleanup
    globfree(&glob_result);

    // done
    return filenames;
}

int main() {
    try { // catch exceptions
        std::vector<std::string> res = glob("*a*"); // files with an "a" in the filename

        for(size_t i = 0; i< res.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << res[i] << '\n';

    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```